# Starting out with Python - Exercise 8.14 Sorting Algorithm. Does this has a name already?

Tags: python, algorithm

So, I am reading the book Starting out with Python.
I came to a point where without teaching me any sorting algorithms,
an exercise asks me to sort a text file containing dates and prices in the following manner.

MM-DD-YYYY:PRICE

i.e.

```
04-05-1993:1.068
04-12-1993:1.079
04-19-1993:1.079
04-26-1993:1.086
05-03-1993:1.086
```

In my frustration i created two lists.
One containing the dates and one containing the prices.

Then I proceeded sorting them with the following function algorithm I came up with.

I am finding the index of the minimum price from the list,
and I am adding the price to the min_to_max_prices_algorithms.

```
def sort_algorithm(dates,prices):

     # Create two lists for storing the results.
     min_to_max_prices = []
     min_to_max_dates = []

     # List I will use to change the prices from str to float.
     price_list = []

     # Set the date_list to dates
     date_list = dates

     # Change the prices to float numbers.
     for index in range(len(prices)):
         price_list.append(float(prices[index]))

     # Algorithm
     for count in range(len(price_list)):

         # Find the minimum price and append it to min_to_max_prices list.
         min_to_max_prices.append(min(price_list))

         # Use the index of the minimum price to add the equivalent
         # date to min_to_max_dates list.                                                 
         min_to_max_dates.append(dates[price_list.index(min(price_list))])

         # Remove the ones added from the lists we search in.
         del date_list[price_list.index(min(price_list))]
         del price_list[price_list.index(min(price_list))]
```

Does this type of algorithm has a name already?
What would be a better solution?
I am sorry but I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own sorting function, use the built-in `sorted` function with a custom key lambda.

Comment: I will look into it ! I kinda just felt that since the writer didn't released that yet, it was part of the plan to have me think about it and come up with one, only using what I've learned from him. Thank you

Comment: Can you describe what your code is doing wrong?

Comment: I am really sorry @glibdud , I was probably not clear in my question. I was asking if there was a better solution without being taught algorithms or anything more than the 'sort' method, or if that algorithm has already a name. I tried finding it myself, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), except you are using a different list for the result, whereas that algorithm sorts the list in-place (i.e. without needing a temporary list). The algorithm works as follows:

```
def selection_sort(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            if lst[i] > lst[j]:
                lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
```

So, basically, every iteration of the outer loop finds the minimum element among the remaining, non-sorted elements.

Selection sort is simple but is not a good sorting algorithm, since its time complexity is `O(n^2)`, while you can do as good as `O(nlogn)` ([see some examples on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)).